# How to mend a worn-out notebook cover, and replace it

Tags: office-supplies

Is there any way I can take off my daughter's spiral-bound notebook cover, because she wrote all over it, and I need to replace it with a new cover, but I tried looking over many social media websites, but none of them told me what to do. I don't know how to sew, and/or I do not have a hole-puncher as the videos recommended. There's no local stores that I know of that has a hole-puncher. So if you could answer my question, that would be great!

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is not that the cover needs replacing, but has writing all over it, my **hack** is

- Cover it with adhesive fabric or film, which you can buy by the sheet or by the roll.

[image]
<sub>*Images from Amazon*</sub>